# Error al querer levantar genexus trial

Tags: genexus

Al poner create en el impacto de analisis me salta lo siguiente en la terminal de genexus:

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" /nologo /p:Configuration=Release /p:FrameworkPath="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" /v:q /m  "C:\Models\Practico\CSharpModel\build\LastBuild.sln"
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(316,9): error MSB6003: No se pudo ejecutar la tarea ejecutable especificada "Csc.exe". No se pudo completar la operaci¢n porque el archivo contiene un virus o software potencialmente no deseado [C:\Models\Practico\CSharpModel\build\reorganization\reorganization.csproj]
Failed: Reorganization
error: Error in reorganization
Failed: Run Developer Menu

Comment: podrías dar mas detalles sobre el problema? que versión de Genexus usas?